# How do I get 3 numbers on each line from 0-100?

Tags: c#

I need to write numbers from 0-100 on the console, like this:

0,1,2

1,2,3

2,3,4

3,4,5

etc.

I really can't seem to figure this out.
Any pointers would be nice!

Comment: Have you tried using a simple (optionally nested) for loop?

Comment: Think about it this way.  You want to print that middle number on each line from 1-99.  Then you just subtract one to the the first number and add one to get the last number for each line.

Comment: sounds like a very, very basic task ;)

Comment: You need to iterate through all integers from 0 to 100 and output i, i+1 and i+2 on each line. The previous sentence is 90% complete code, just translate it into C# :)

Comment: @someone Yeah I tried a while loop, but couldn't crack the code for having 3 numbers on 1 line.

Comment: @EstebanP yeah, I know it is and I've tried a couple of things, just can't crack it. Just starting out.

Comment: @YeldarKurmangaliyev that was exactly the way I was thinking of doing it! I jsut can't seem to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's quite easy actually, something like:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0},{1},{2}", i, i+1, i+2));
}
```

It will goes from 0 to 101 because it always prints 3 numbers so the last iteration would be 99,100 otherwise. If you want it that way just edit `i < 100` with `i < 99`.

Comment: Actually you want `i<99` so that the last line will be "98,99,100"

Answer (score 2):

A LINQ way of achieving it:

```
Enumerable.Range(2, 99).ToList()
        .ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine($"{x - 2},{x - 1},{x}"));
```